# Pass a date from another fragment to caldroid fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, caldroid

Hello guys I´m wondering, how can I pass a date whit a button click to a caldroid calendar fragment? So I can edit that date color make clickable etc.

Caldroid Fragment:

```
    public class Caldroid_fragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.caldroid_calendar, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String dt = Testes.notas.get("Teste");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date teste_portugues = null;
    try {
        teste_portugues = sdf.parse(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN);


    CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();



    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.START_DAY_OF_WEEK, CaldroidFragment.MONDAY);
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(green,teste_portugues);
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction t = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.caldroidCal, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();
}}
```

Parent class of the two fragments:

```
    public class Testes extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener hourSetListener;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;
private Button date_button;
private Button hora_picker;
private TextView date_text;
private TextView hora_text;

public static Bundle notas = new Bundle();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testes);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);




}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_testes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()){
       case go_to_fazer_media:{
           if (item.isChecked())
               item.setChecked(false);
            else{
           Intent i = new Intent(Testes.this,Formas.class);
           startActivity(i);
               return true;
            }
       }
       case definicoes:{
           if (item.isChecked())
               item.setChecked(false);
           else{
              return true;
           }
       }
   }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){

            case 0:
                Tab1tests tab1 =  new Tab1tests();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2calendar tab2 =  new Tab2calendar();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Adicionar Testes";
            case 1:
                return "Mapa de Testes";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

The fragment that im trying to pass information from :

```
public class Tab1tests extends Fragment {


private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener hourSetListener;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;
private Button date_button;
private Button hora_button;
private TextView date_text;
private TextView hora_text;
public static Button add_test;
private String dt;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1tests, container, false);

    add_test = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_test);
    date_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_button);
    hora_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_text);
    hora_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_button);
    date_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);


            date_button.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            DatePickerDialog date_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                                    dateSetListener,
                                    year, month, day);
                            date_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            date_dialog.show();


                        }

                        ;
                    }

            );

    dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            date_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            date_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            date_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dt = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            try {
                sdf.parse(dt);
                date_text.setText(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };




    hora_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_button);

    hora_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, hourSetListener, hora, minutos, true);
                    mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
            }
    );

    hourSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hora, int minutos) {
            hora_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            hora_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hora_text.setText(hora + ":" + minutos);
        }
    };

    hora_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,hourSetListener,hora,minutos,true);
            mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            mTimePicker.show();
        }

    });

    date_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog date_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    getActivity(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    dateSetListener,
                    year, month, day);
            date_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            date_dialog.show();
        }
    });



    add_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            Testes.notas.putString("Teste"+ contador3,dt);


        }
    });




    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: can you add some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure I will edit it